# Changing from portrait to landscape layout?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to switch to from a portrait to landscape layout. I've already switched up the buttons in page and print set up and for some reason, the print layout icon shows my page still having portrait features in a non-completely filled landscape icon.

I'm a graduate student in urban planning who still has his GIS training wheels on.

Answer (score 12):

Check your printer settings - if no printer then export to PDF - make sure the **PAPER SETTINGS** match **PRINTER SETTINGS** and tiling is off.

[image]

[image]

Full details
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sm00000003000000.htm